# SQL Statement to Fine Non Decimal in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL statement in Mysql DB to find the non decimal number from a decimal number. My data is like this.

```
Table: Products

ProductId
10.20
12.15
136.42

I just need results like below.

ProductId
10
12
136


Any ideas?
```

Comment: Do you want to find them, or round them in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use FLOOR () .

```
SELECT FLOOR(ProductId)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of `ROUND()` or `FLOOR()` listed on [mathematical functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html) for MySQL.

```
SELECT ROUND(ProductId)
FROM youTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you appear to be converting from a numeric/float to an int, I would suggest an explicit conversion:

```
select cast(ProductId as int)
```

If the ProductId is stored as a character string, MySQL will convert the leading characters (including the ".") to a number.  Then it will do the cast.